# Error: CORS in laravel/VueJS ajax request

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, cors, vue.js

I am getting cross origin problem while placing an AJAX request using VueJS to my Laravel Application.
I Have written back end API with Laravel 5.3

Comment: You will need to handle origin requests in your API. You can use something like this: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors

Comment: you should always use google before asking question or at least Stack's search. You would get at least couple of answers without asking the same question as many, many people

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the Cors Middleware I use:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CorsMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $headers = [
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'      => '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods'     => 'POST, GET, OPTIONS',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => 'true',
            'Access-Control-Max-Age'           => '86400',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'     => 'Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With'
        ];

        if ($request->isMethod('OPTIONS')) {
            return response()->json('{"method":"OPTIONS"}', 200, $headers);
        }

        $response = $next($request);
        foreach($headers as $key => $value) {
            $response->header($key, $value);
        }

        return $response;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I updated this middle-ware and used with my laravel 5.3

Answer (score 3):

If you are doing an [XMLHttpRequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) to a different domain than your page is on, your browser will block it as it usually allows a request in the same origin for security reasons. You need to do something different when you want to do a cross-domain request. A tutorial about how to achieve that is *[Using CORS](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/)*.

When you are using postman they are not restricted by this policy. Quoted from *[Cross-Origin XMLHttpRequest](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr.html)*:

> Regular web pages can use the XMLHttpRequest object to send and receive data from remote servers, but they're limited by the same origin policy. Extensions aren't so limited. An extension can talk to remote servers outside of its origin, as long as it first requests cross-origin permissions.

To solve this, your external API server has to support cors request by setting following headers:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
```

which can be done by [laravel-cors](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors) as suggested in the comments.